# How to convert currency from string format to number format?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to convert currency from string format to number format.

For example my string variable value is `@"10 lakh"`. The string value for this converted into number format would be 1000000. How can one make this type of conversion?

*(Converting 10 lakh to 1000000, this is the issue)*

Comment: OMG.... I can convert its reverse way by `NSNumberFormatter`

Comment: @user1980105 Anoop Vaidya is a skilled programmer, his services will cost you at least $150/h. StackOverflow is not here to give you code but to help you with problems of your own code, or point you in a good direction. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)!

Comment: @user1980105 you want this for 20 lakh,30 lakh,40 lakh..... right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
- (NSNumber *)multiplierForKey:(NSString *)key
{

    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"thousand":@1000, @"lakh":@100000, @"million":@1000000, @"crore":@100000000};
    NSNumber *value = dict[[key lowercaseString]];
    return value?value:@1;
}

- (void)findMultiplier{

    NSString *string = @"10 lakh";

    NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    if ([components count]==2) {
        NSNumber *value = components[0];
        NSString *key = components[1];
        NSNumber *multiplier = [self multiplierForKey:key];

        NSDecimalNumber *decimalValue = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[value decimalValue]];
        NSDecimalNumber *multiplierValue = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[multiplier decimalValue]];

        NSDecimalNumber *finalValue = [decimalValue decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:multiplierValue];
        NSLog(@"Value : %@",finalValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is only for 1o lakh please generalize this :)

Comment: @AshutoshMishra I just gave a generic solution with other similar commonly used names. If you don't want just use a string comparison and find the multiplier.

Answer (score 1):

You can make switch cases according to your denominations. By choosing particular switch case you can choose the desired value. I don't think there is predefined method to accomplish this.

hope this helps.

Comment: A good suggestion. I guess you need to make an array of such notations and their corresponding multipliers. Use a predicate or something to find matching notation and get the multiplier